# Is $l^2$ is separable banach space?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

> Is $l^2$ is separable Banach space?

I had proved the following 2 lemmas:

1) $l^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty $ is complete

2)$l^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty $ is separable.

With this, I can conclude that $l^2$ is separable Banach space.

But I also proved using Baire Category theorem that any infinite dimensional Banach space must have Hamel basis uncountable.

But as space is separable it must have a countable basis.

Where I am missing?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ell^2$ *is* a separable Banach space indeed (even Hilbert space, because it has inner product to give the norm).

It has a countable *topological base* and a countable orthonormal base (which is also a Schauder base, which is its generalisation in Banach spaces) but an uncountable linear vector space basis (aka Hamel basis). These are different notions of bases so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Dear Sir, I am beginer of Functional Analysis . Please Can you give me some reference where I can get more about 2 different notion .

Comment: @SRJ have you tried Wikipedia and other online resources (mathworld)?

Comment: Dear Sir Form that I got that In case of Scheder basis for any element we have unique series  which approximate that element . And In case of Hamel bais we require to have finite linear combination. Is this correct?

Comment: @SRJ yes, Schauder bases rely on convergence of series and Hamel is just the standard finite linear combination basis in any vector space. The first needs a topology, and is more useful in analysis generally.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir